# How to attach JavaDocs to a .jar file with multiple libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, activemq-classic, javadoc

I downloaded the `activemq-5.11.1.jar` and it's basically an all-purpose .jar file containing ActiveMQ, JMS, and other utilities like slf4j. However, JavaDocs didn't come with them.

I downloaded the ActiveMQ 5.11.1 source and attached the JavaDocs. Now I can see the JavaDocs for ActiveMQ related classes, but not for `javax.jms` classes.

If it helps, I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The JMS spec comes from the Apache Geronimo project. But there ain't not much java doc to talk about in [these files](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1/).

If you look at the [glassfish dependency](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.mq/jms/4.5.2/) instead, you would get pretty good documentation. Not sure if eclipse let you wap it but worth a try.

Glassfish is the reference implementation, so that source should be the go-to place for documentation and reference. That JMS spec could not be used by ActiveMQ (by license reasons - GPL vs Apache2), so the less documented but compatible Geronimo dependency is used instead. Do not simply override the dependency from Geronimo with Glassfish as it might cause license trouble for you.